# What is wrong in the following reasoning for calculate this limit

Tags: limits

I have been told that

1. $f(x)$ has a slant right asynthote $m_1x+q_1$
2. $g(x)$ has a slant right asynthote $m_2x+q_2$

$m_1,m_2 \neq 0$

They ask me if $f(x) \sim g(x)$ when $x$ goes to infinity.

**I don't even know what the question means**. I made the following reasoning BUT I feel that something is not right with it:

**1** means that

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x) - m_1x+q_1)= 0$$

that can be written as

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to+\infty}( m_1x+q_1)$$

the same goes for $g(x)$ hence:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x) = \lim_{x\to+\infty}( m_2x+q_2)$$

I claim that $$\dfrac{\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x)}=\lim_{x\to+\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac{\lim_{x\to+\infty} m_1x+q_1}{\lim_{x\to+\infty} m_2x+q_2}=\lim_{x\to+\infty} \dfrac{m_1x+q_1}{m_2x+q_2} = \dfrac{m1}{m2}$$

I have the feeling that this is wrong. Could you please help me find out where the reasoning is wrong?

Thank you

EDIT:

**Would it be possible to show that $f_(x) + 2g(x)$ has horizontal asymptote instead? I don't really know how to procede.**

Comment: The second and third limits are both infinity, therefore the second equality in the last line is not justified as written.

Comment: i think the idea is fine, but there are some semantics and details that need to be fixed. in particular, when you say $\lim a = \lim b$ it does not follow that $$\frac{\lim a}{\lim b} = 1$$ if both limits are infinite, consider $a(x) = x$ and $b(x) = x^2$ for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close (and get the right answer), but your approach not quite correct, since $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}(m_1x+q_1)$ is infinite, and the limit manipulation rules don't all work with infinite limits. Thus, for example, it's incorrect to state (as you do) that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x)}$; the right side evaluates as $\frac{\infty}\infty$ (one or both infinities might be positive or negative), which has no defined value, while the left side might have a defined value (e.g., $1$, if $f=g$).

Instead, starting from  $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-(m_1x+q_1))=0$, we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-(m_1x+q_1)}{m_1x+q_1} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{f(x)}{m_1x+q_1}-1\right) = 0$, so  $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{m_1x+q_1} = 1$. Similarly $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g(x)}{m_2x+q_2} = 1$. Now take the reciprocal of the latter limit and multiply it by the first. See if you can continue from there.

Comment: @Y.Forman honestly I don't get your point in your answer but let me think about it. I will edit my question right away but I think you all know what I mean. orole only flamed the topic. He's being rude for no reason.

Comment: @HardCore Please feel free to comment again if you'd like further clarification!

Comment: @Y.Forman ok I followed your step and IF I made the calculation right It turns ot that $f/g$ tends to $m_1/m_2$ as $x$ goes to infinity. But That should not be right.

Comment: @HardCore Why not?

Comment: how can you show that the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{(m_1x+q_1)} =1$ in the first place?

Comment: @HardCore Edited to clarify.

Comment: You are too kind. Good point thank you. I understand what you did. One question. All limit theorems that I found for example to apply$\lim_{x \to \infty} f/g = lim_{x \to \infty} f / lim_{x \to \infty} g$ always say: if $lim_{x \to \infty} f$ and $lim_{x \to \infty} g$ EXIST then ... But even if the limit is infinite it exists? Right ? so maybe they should say EXIST FINITE?

Comment: @HardCore This is a question of convention, but usually "the limit exists" means "the limit exists in the real numbers," i.e., the limit exists finitely.